# Вызвать функцию из функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

Я только начал изучать JavaScript. Надо вызвать функцию,  из функции пытаюсь не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Код:

```
    self.AutoSearch = function (searchPanelUpdateRequired, isMobileOverride,
        function (){console.log("111111111111");
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'visitor interaction',
            'interaction_name': 'vehicle search'
        });}) {
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if ((windowWidth > 500) || (isMobileOverride == true)) {
            if (self.SearchData.Configuration.SearchAutoUpdate()) {
                self.DoSearch(1, searchPanelUpdateRequired, false);
            }
            else {
                if (searchPanelUpdateRequired != false) {
                    self.UpdateSearchPanel();
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: функция вызывается добавлением двух скобок после ее имени `nameFunction ()`. Вашем случае будет `self.AutoSearch (arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @Дмытрык  внутри функции надо вызвать еще одну функцию. не знаю как вызвать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы вызвать анонимную функцию есть несколько вариантов:

1. Необходимо саму функцию обернуть в круглые скобки и сразу же после последней скобки (без каких либо знаков препинания) вызвать `();`;

   ```js
   (function (){
   console.log("work");
   })();
   ```

2.Похож на первый, но в круглые скобки оборачивается и функция и ее вызов:

```js
(function (str){
console.log(str);
}("work"));
```

В вызов анонимной функции можно передать и аргументы. Как в примере №2.

В Вашем примере что-то напутано (как мне кажется), так что - примените конструкцию вызова анонимной функции сами.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 2):

```
 self.AutoSearch()
```

рекомендую почитать
https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function